# How to Audit an @ManyToOne relation with Hibernate envers

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

When I'm trying to do an audition with my Hibernate envers, my two relations that are @ManyToOne return this error:

```
Method threw 'javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException' exception. Cannot evaluate io.sucesso.bps.gallery.domain.Arquivo$HibernateProxy$suSDDjYF.toString()
```

OS -> Windows 11
Java Version -> 17.0.5

Comment: Could you please provide information about your `Entity` and its config? And maybe about your audit tb tables? Which one are created/used?
Usually the `EntityNotFoundException` issue shows that you are not tracking BOTH sides of your relationship. You can audit single object or in case of relationships you need BOTH sides be added to envers.